# Need to new create array in the name of the first element of the array

Tags: ruby

I have an array

```
a=["ncd",0.1,0.2,0.3.0.4]
```

Now, Can I create an array in the name of ncd without declaring the variable, for an example, another array has to be created in the name of ncd like

```
ncd=[0.1,0.2,0.3.0.4]
```

but I wouldn't do this statically as shown above, I need to pop up the element from the array and need to create the array,

For an example, I need to create the array using a[0], Is this possible in Ruby?

Comment: why dont you have a hash? `a = { "ncd" => [0.1,0.2,0.3.0.4] }`. Then you can do `a['ncd']`

Comment: That thought just arises in my mind and you have written it, thanks.

Comment: Or you can use instance variables

Comment: Since  Ruby v1.9+ it has not been possible to create a local variable dynamically.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you.

Comment: @LukasBaliak I can't use instance variables, I need to create dynamic variables.

Comment: You can create dynamic instance variables if you use `instance_variable_set("@ncd", "test")`

Comment: @LukasBaliak Ah! Thank you, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to have a hash

```
a = { "ncd" => [0.1,0.2,0.3.0.4] }
```

Or if you have some array of arrays like this

```
a = [['ncd1', 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], ['ncd2', 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]]
```

you can use some method to get dynamic values

```
def dynamic(ar)
  ar.each_with_object({}) do |el, hash|
    hash[el.first] = el[1..-1]
  end
end

dynamic a
#=> {"ncd1"=>[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], "ncd2"=>[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]}
```

And then

```
dynamic(a)['ncd1']
#=> [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

But this looks like some kind of ugly syntax in ruby.

**UPDATE 1**

Maybe it would be less ugly to pass key as second parameter, i.e.

```
def dynamic(ar, key)
  ar.each_with_object({}) do |el, hash|
    hash[el.first] = el[1..-1]
  end[key]
end

dynamic a, 'ncd1'
```

It is up to you to decide.

**UPDATE 2**

I forgot...
You can do `el.drop(1)` instead of `el[1..-1]`